# Deny access to files inside folder but allow a REST API

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am using this `.htaccess` to simulate a folder full of files (a simple REST API):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule files/(.*)$ api.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Let's call this folder `magicfolder` where I am using this `.htaccess` file.
In fact, there is only `api.php` that is creating every file that is requested.
So, an url like `mysite.com/magicfolder/files/image.jpg` is converted into `mysite.com/magicfolder/api.php?file=image.jpg`.
This is great. But I want also to add some rules that makes any real file that exists in `magicfolder` (logs and even `api.php`) to be inaccessible for users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Make sure your htaccess rules file is present inside magicfolder folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/?$ api.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: It works. Perfect! Thank you! GOD bless you! :)

Comment: @Junior, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.