# htaccess deny access from Browser searchbar but allow a REST API

Tags: php, rest, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the next configuration in my .htaccess and thats for call php files without .php extension

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

For example:

> How it was -> myapi.com/v1/stock.php?shoes=8-11

> How it is  -> myapi.com/v1/stock?shoes=8-11 (without .php)

And what I need is that the api can only be invoked through the Rest API calls and not through the browser and without losing the configuration that I already have.

Comment: URL rewriting has nothing to do with what kind of software can access your website. You need to implement some kind of *authentication* inside your application.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks for your help, please check this another similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691489/deny-access-to-files-inside-folder-but-allow-a-rest-api 
I think is similar to mine and if I try to mixed both then the result comes as broken.

Comment: That question is not about preventing the browser from accessing anything, it's just about avoiding two URLs accessing the same thing. Either way, you need to show what you've tried, and what happened - "the result comes as broken" is not a useful description.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP for clearing it up. Let see, I have this API and an example of one of endpoints (https://api.beatfeel.com/v1/user/getRecommended?user=1&cuantity=3), The issue is, I want to be able to access that endpoint only using REST API rest, using fetch or others, but I don't want it to be accessible through the browser and to see the json with all the data. At the moment I have put a validation in the code that checks if the user is using the browser but by changing the header it can be skipped.

Comment: Even if you wrote some code that reliably distinguished "user entered the URL in the address bar" from "user wrote some JS to fetch the URL with AJAX" or "user fetched the page using CURL on the command-line", what would you gain? I suspect what you really want is to distinguish "user who I have granted access to" from "user who guessed the URL but shouldn't have access"; and that, as I said before, is a question of **authentication** - you need to implement a username and password, or an API token, or an OAuth flow, or any of dozens of other schemes you'll find info about online.

Comment: Thx @IMSoP for your answer, I already have implemente user/pass token validation. It is merely to prevent any unnecessary querying or anyone messing with it unintentionally

Comment: If the authentication is working, determining *how* somebody makes a failed request is like trying to determine if someone rattling a locked door is wearing gloves or not - they can't "mess with" anything anyway, so who cares?